# What is attention penalty in speech transformer paper? (updated)

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, speech-recognition, tf.keras, transformer-model

github: https://github.com/sephiroce/tfsr/tree/exprimental

I'm trying to reproduce recognition accuracies described in the speech transformer paper [1]. 
The attention penalty is a technique I could not fully understand. 
This is the description of the attention penalty in the paper.

"In addition, we encouraged the model attending to closer positions by adding 
 bigger penalty on the attention weights of more distant position-pairs."

I understood as it means adding smaller negative values for more away from the diagonal on scaled attention logits (before masking) except for the first multi-head attention in decoders.

This is a code snippet for computing attention weights.

```
  # Q * trans(K): (..., seq_len_q, seq_len_k)
  matmul_qk = tf.matmul(query, key, transpose_b=True)

  # scaled matmul_qk: ( Q * trans(K) ) / sqrt(d_k)
  dimension_of_key = tf.cast(tf.shape(key)[-1], tf.float32)
  scaled_attention_logits = matmul_qk / tf.math.sqrt(dimension_of_key)

  # add the mask to the scaled tensor
  if mask is not None:
    scaled_attention_logits += (mask * -1e9)

  # softmax is normalized on the last axis (seq_len_k) so that the scores
  # add up to 1.
  attention_weights = tf.nn.softmax(scaled_attention_logits, axis=-1)

  # Adding penalty to attention weights and linearly re-normalize it.
  if attention_penalty is not None and att_penalty_scale > 0:
    attention_weights += (attention_penalty * att_penalty_scale)
    attention_weights += tf.math.abs(tf.math.reduce_min(attention_weights))
    inv_sum = 1 / tf.math.reduce_sum(attention_weights, axis=-1)
    attention_weights = tf.einsum('ijlm,ijl->ijlm', attention_weights, inv_sum)
```

The source code snippet below is for creating an attention penalty matrix.
I could not find any efficient way to create an attention penalty matrix for the second multi-head attention weights in decoders since the attention maps are not diagonal. Thus first I am trying to apply the attention penalty to encoders.
The source code assigns linearly bigger penalties for more distant elements from diagonal.
There are two hyper-parameters such as an attention_penalty_scale (this is similar to `penalty_values` which Jindřich suggested) and a width of the diagonal line.
I might be able to add an option such as `stripe_step_size`. Currently `stripe_step_size` can be interpreted as 1.

```
def create_attention_penalty(inp_len, tar_len, num_heads, attention_penalty_width):
  max_inp_len = tf.cast(tf.math.reduce_max(inp_len), tf.int32)
  n_batch = tf.shape(inp_len)[0]

  enc_att_penalty = tf.ones([n_batch, num_heads, max_inp_len, max_inp_len])

  accum = tf.zeros(([n_batch, num_heads, max_inp_len, max_inp_len]))
  for i in range(attention_penalty_width - 1, max_inp_len - 1):
    accum += tf.linalg.band_part(enc_att_penalty, i, i, name=None) - 1

  enc_att_penalty = accum

  return enc_att_penalty, None
```

Even though I implemented as I understand, I could not gain any accuracy improvement. And there is another down-side of this implementation. The training speed was getting slower.

Q) How to efficiently apply this attention penalty method for square and non-square attention weights?

Reference
[1] Linhao Dong, Shuang Xu, Bo Xu, Speech-Transformer: A No-Recurrence Sequence-to-Sequence Model for Speech Recognition, ICASSP 2018, https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8462506

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you understand it well. They probably did a stripe around the diagonal, something like:

```py
attention_penalty = (1 - tf.linalg.band_part(scaled_attention_logits, stripe_size, stripe_size)) * penalty
```

However, you probably need to experiment more with what the `strip_size` and `penalty_values` should be because the paper does not say much. Or you can try to write to the authors.

Comment: Thank you very much @Jindřich. I modified the source code to add the attention penalty on attention weights rather than attention logits (a.k.a. attention energy). And I implemented "create_attention_penalty" method. (please check the updated question.) With the attention penalty masking, I did not get any improved accuracy even though I trained and decoded with the same attention penalty. I think as you suggested I need to find some good hyper-parameters.